# How do I find the unit vector in the direction of the minimal rate of change?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, vector, vector-calculus

A ball falls on the surface $x^4 z+x^9 y^2+y^2 z^3=65$ at the point (-1,-3,2). How do I find a three-dimensional unit vector in the direction that the ball will begin to roll.  I know that the ball will begin to roll in the steepest downhill direction, which means it's in the direction of minimal rate of change.

Comment: Are you sure this is posted on the correct site? Maybe you intended this for https://math.stackexchange.com/questions as opposed to this specialized site for the computer program Mathematica.

Comment: The point $(-4,-5, 2)$ is not on the surface.

Comment: Yes, I realized I put the question on the wrong site and I put in the wrong point as well.

Comment: Look for `Grad` in the Mathematica documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we need to get z[x,y] from the implicit equation:

```
z[x_, y_] = z /. Solve[eq, z][[1]];
```

To simplify, we assume that the ball has mass==1 and the gravitational  acceleration == 1. Then the acceleration is equal to the negative gradient and we can solve the resulting diff.equation using NDSolve assuming further, that the ball starts at {-1,-3,2} and is initially at rest. NDSolve gives us replacement rules for x[t] and y[t]. And as we already know z[x,y] we can get a 3D function: sol[t] that describes the trajectory:

```
sol[t_] = {x[t], y[t], z[x[t], y[t]]} /. 
   NDSolve[{{x''[t], y''[t]} == -Grad[z[x[t], y[t]], {x[t], y[t]}], 
      x[0] == -1, x'[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0, y[0] == -3}, {x[t], 
      y[t]}, {t, 0, 5}][[1]];
```

We can now draw the trajectory using ParametricPlot3D together with a piece of the surface using ContourPlot3D:

```
Show[{
  ContourPlot3D[
   x^4 z + x^9 y^2 + y^2 z^3 == 65, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -8, -2}, {z, 4, 0}]
  , ParametricPlot3D[sol[t], {t, 0, 5}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.01], Red}]
  }]
```

[image]